# Change SSH TTY session type to X11 at console?

Tags: debian, x11, kde, display-manager

I have a Debian 12 VM that and when I boot it remotely the user session is a TTY, can I have it launch an X11 session at the console end?

#### Attempt A

- KDE is installed
- I have selected plasma-x11 as my default session
  manager
- I have changed the default display manager to sddm

```
loginctl
SESSION  UID USER   SEAT TTY  
      3 1000 user1      pts/0

1 sessions listed.

loginctl show-session 3 -p Type                                   
Type=tty

update-alternatives --config x-session-manager             
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/startxfce4        50        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/startplasma-x11   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/startxfce4        50        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/xfce4-session     40        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/sddm

ls /usr/share/xsessions
lightdm-xsession.desktop  plasma.desktop  xfce.desktop
```

but my user keeps login into a TTY session. How can I solve it?

#### Attempt B

- I have tried starting the display-manager.service

```
systemctl start display-manager.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'lightdm.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====

loginctl show-session 22 -p Type
Type=tty
```

but it started lightdm instead of sddm even though I set x-session-manager to /usr/bin/startplasma-x11, and the session is still type=tty.

#### Attempt C

- I have manually started sddm
- I have tried startx, startplasma-x11 and startkde, but to no avail.

```
systemctl start sddm.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'sddm.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====

startx
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
^Cxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.

startkde
zsh: command not found: startkde

startplasma-x11
$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.
```

As a result, an x11 session has been started for the sddm user instead of changing my user's session to X11.

```
loginctl
SESSION  UID USER   SEAT  TTY  
     22 1000 user1       pts/0
     24  111 sddm   seat0 

2 sessions listed.
```

When I have a regular X11 session, it's my user's session, not the session for the display manager user.

#### Attempt D

- I have tried startX with root privileges and detaching it, so it doesn't block the terminal.

```
doas startx &
[2] 2446
[2]  + suspended (tty output)  doas startx
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When `sddm` is running a session as user `sddm`, it normally means it's displaying a GUI login screen. When you use it to log in, the user will be switched to the actual logged-in account.

But the X11 server is starting on the *VM console*, not in your pseudo-TTY-based remote session.

If you want a remote X11 session, you'll need:

- a X11 display server running *on your local workstation*, appropriate to its operating system
- a SSH session *with X11 forwarding enabled*
- the `xauth` command and X11 client libraries available on the remote host/VM.

Specifically, **you don't need a remote X11 server at all** for a X11-based remote session: it does not have to be running, or even installed. With VNC or RDP, it would be a different story.

When all these pre-requisites are met, you should automatically get a terminal session that has the `DISPLAY` environment set to `localhost:10` (the display number may be different, but it will be 10 or greater). The `XAUTHORITY` environment variable might also be set, if necessary in your distribution. At that point, you should be able to just run

```
startplasma-x11 &
```

to start a KDE session.

Comment: I have also been trying to go this route, but to no avail.

- The xauth command is available everywhere. - libx11-dev is installed at the remote VM and libx11 at my local machine.
- The remote VM has ```ForwardX11``` and ```ForwardX11Trusted``` set to yes in the client config file and ```X11Fowarding``` set to yes and ```X11DisplayOffset``` set to 10 in the sshd config file. They are uncommented and the deamon has been restarted.
- I login via ```SSH -X``` and my $DISPLAY variable is empty. 
I do not understand why.

Comment: If you use `ssh -X` to connect, and the remote `$DISPLAY` remains empty, that most likely means the local SSH client failed to connect to the local X11 display server, and therefore decided that trying to request X11 forwarding will be futile. What is the OS of your local/host system?

Comment: The remote VM is Debian 12. The local machine is Manjaro.

Comment: Do you have `$DISPLAY` set in your local session in Manjaro when you start the SSH connection? Can you run X11 applications locally? If not, then the SSH client will not be able to forward the X11 connection since there is apparently no X11 server reachable at the local system which would process the incoming X11 draw requests.

Comment: It is set to ```:0``` and ```echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE``` returns x11. I am running KDE and as far as I am concerned, KDE is a hybrid using Wayland for some things and Xorg for others.

Comment: Can you start a simple X11 client, such as `xclock` or `xterm`, locally on Manjaro? If that does not work, you'll have to fix that first. Also, have you restarted `sshd` after modifying its configuration (in Debian, that is `systemctl restart ssh` for historical reasons).

Comment: Yes and yes. Those are not the problems.

Comment: I hate it when stuff like this happens **I put my laptop to sleep (close the lid). Walk home. Try to SSH with Xforwarding again. The remote VM doesn't shake hands. Try it 5 minutes later. It shakes hands and ```$DISPLAY = :10.0```** I changed 0 settings and to my knowledge no computers were rebooted and no services restarted. I do not know what fixed it.